# Swift Unit test case is falling into Tab-bar controller

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uitableview, tabbar

I have created require mock for view controller with name and the identifier and I have test it into different code , it working fine . Now I am trying to use same code with table view at indexPath but this time I am using Tab-bar controller but the problem is the unit test case is falling and it not matching the data I have into mock ..

Here is the Co-ordinator code ..

```
class AppCoordinator: Coordinator {
    var tabBarController: UITabBarController
    private var peoplesCoordinator:PeoplesCoordinator?

    private var roomssCoordinator:RoomsCoordinator?

    init(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {
        self.tabBarController = tabBarController
    }
    
    func start() {
       
        let peopleTabFlow = createPeoplesFlow()
        let roomsTabFlow = createRoomsTab()

        tabBarController.viewControllers = [peopleTabFlow, roomsTabFlow]
    }
```

Here is the code for view controller ..

```
class PeoplesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
   
    var peopleViewModel:PeopleViewModelType!
    weak var coordinator: PeoplesCoordinatoryType!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        peopleViewModel.fetchPeoples(baseUrl: EndPoint.baseUrl, path: Path.people)
    }    
}

extension PeoplesViewController:UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return peopleViewModel.peoplessCount
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? PeopleTableViewCell else{return UITableViewCell()}
       
        if let people = peopleViewModel.getPeopleDetailFor(index: indexPath.row) {
            cell.setData(staff: people)
        }
        return cell
    }
    
}

extension PeoplesViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let staff = peopleViewModel.getPeopleDetailFor(index: indexPath.row) {
            coordinator.navigatToPeopleDetails(people: staff)
        }
    }
}

extension PeoplesViewController: PeoplesViewable {
    func refreshUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.isHidden = false
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func showError() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the cell code ..

```
class PeopleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageAvatar: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobTitle: UILabel!
   
}
```

Here is the unit testing part ..

```
final class PeopleViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {
    var peopleViewModel: PeoplesViewModel!
     
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        let peoplesViewController = PeoplesViewController()
        let mockNetworkMaanger = MockNetworkManager()
        peopleViewModel = PeoplesViewModel(serviceManager: mockNetworkMaanger, delegate: peoplesViewController)
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        peopleViewModel = nil
    }
func testTableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath() {
        if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StaffViewer") as? PeoplesViewController {
            vc.peopleViewModel = peopleViewModel
            vc.loadViewIfNeeded()

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            let cell = vc.tableView(vc.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath as IndexPath) as? PeopleTableViewCell

            XCTAssertEqual(cell?.firstNameLabel.text, "Maggie")

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the unit testing part , it shows this error .. although the values is correct.

**testTableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath(): XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("Label")") is not equal to ("Optional("Maggie")")**